# $f$ isn't necessarily bijective but still $f^{-1}$ shows up

Tags: continuity, compactness

[If $A$ is compact, is then $f(A)$ compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111758/if-a-is-compact-is-then-fa-compact)

The answer here by David Mitra uses $f^{-1}$, however we only know $f$ is continuous in its domain, so how do we come up with the inverse?

Its not mentioned to be strictly montone either. I do think it's a stupid question but I really want to know.

Comment: If $A$ is a set and $f:X\to Y$ a function, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is always defined and is by definition $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in A\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any function $f: X \to Y$ and any set $A \subseteq Y$ we define $f^{-1}(A)$ as $\{x \in X: f(x) \in A\}$. This is called the inverse image of $A$ under $f$.

Comment: Thanks, I got confused

Comment: @Shamim It may in fact be confusing. The symbol $f^{-1}$ has two interpretations: (1)  For each **subset** $A \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(A)$ denotes the inverse image (also called preimage) of $A$ which is a subset of $X$. Thus you may regard $f^{-1}$ as function from the power set of $Y$ to the  power set of $X$. (2) If $f : X \to Y$ is bijective, then it is standard to write $f^{-1} : Y \to X$ for the inverse bijection. Usually it is absolutely clear from the context which interpretation is meant.

Comment: Yes, I knew that definition beforehand but forgot right then, so I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

In your given link, $f^{-1}$ is only used just for preimage of the set $A$.
So, in this case, $f^{-1}$ need to be just a relation!
You can say , bijective is necessary, if $f^{-1}$ is used as $f^{-1} (a) $ for $a\in Im(f)$, which is a inverse function of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer